# How do I grant access to all subfolders of a folder in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

Here is the policy I wrote in Amazon S3.  I thought it should give access to subfolders because of the * but it is giving access denied errors when the user tries to create or view subfolders.  How can I change this to work?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRootAndMediaListingOfCompanyBucket",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "media/"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInMediaFolder",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucket/media/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

More details:

I logged into the console as the user.  I went to the media folder.  I then click on a folder inside of media and got the message "Error access denied".

Comment: Yes, it should do so. Could you please provide more details of what you are trying to do, how you are doing it (console, CLI?) and exactly what error message you are receiving. Also, what policy is associated with the user in IAM (as opposed to the Bucket Policy)? Feel free to Edit your question to add these details.

Comment: I've updated the details of the question to give the info you asked for.  I only gave this policy to a specific group in my organization, so how somebody be able to come along and delete my data?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I thought you had assigned this as a Bucket Policy. In that case, it is safe to assign to specific Users/Groups.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't get it to work, either. Your policy seems to be based on [Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/). I can get it to work for `media/` but I can't get it to work on subfolders within `media/`.

Comment: So is there a different way of writing it that would work?

Comment: I was unable to find a way to get it to work. Hopefully someone else can provide a suitable answer. Alternatively, if you subscribe to AWS Support, you can open a case with them to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing permissions to list the contents of the media folder. Add the following statement to your policy.

Note: Your policy should be added to the user(s) and not to the bucket itself. A better choice is to create an IAM group, attach the policy to the group and then add each user to the group (which you mentioned that you are doing).

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowListingOfMediaFolder",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mycoolbucket"],
  "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["media/*"]}}
},
```

Answer (score 7):

With this policy, I'm able to grant access to all subfolders of a folder in Amazon S3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<<bucketname>>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "foldername/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<<bucketname>>/foldername/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Both these policies are needed? Or only one of these two?

Comment: @rineez you can use either one of them. You don't need both, these are just different ways to write the same thing. (If you ignore the action-params)